# Cannot access Drupal /admin/modules or /admin/people after upgrade 9.2.15 -> 9.3.15

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php, drupal-9

Like the title says, everything worked as expected until I upgraded to 9.3.15 from 9.2.15 Its is a composer based installation.

When I try to access one of the paths the first gives me this

> The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
>
> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "user.admin_permissions.module" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

The people option give me this:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "user.role.settings" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
```

There was no error on composer, no errors in any logs though this appears in my access.log

```
- [06/Jun/2022:15:06:56 +0000] "GET /admin/people/permissions HTTP/1.0" 500 3053 "https://d9d.text-based.net/admin/people/permissions/administrator" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
```

Here is the full error that is displayed on the page:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route "user.role.settings" does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 206 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).

Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskDefault->getRouteParameters() (Line: 310)
Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getTasksBuild() (Line: 358)
Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalTaskManager->getLocalTasks() (Line: 95)
Drupal\Core\Menu\Plugin\Block\LocalTasksBlock->build() (Line: 171)
Drupal\block\BlockViewBuilder::preRender()
call_user_func_array() (Line: 101)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doTrustedCallback() (Line: 772)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doCallback() (Line: 363)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 435)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 201)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 463)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (Line: 43)
__TwigTemplate_00188c1691be8aad1e9679a8355ec8b1aad8fb0e1a0552901f64354cc31fc535->doDisplay() (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling() (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 55)
twig_render_template() (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 422)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 201)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 463)
Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (Line: 86)
__TwigTemplate_52bf370994174cae6411a160df9bc52e747d5a7e02be204f64e1e34dad454a33->doDisplay() (Line: 405)
Twig\Template->displayWithErrorHandling() (Line: 378)
Twig\Template->display() (Line: 390)
Twig\Template->render() (Line: 55)
twig_render_template() (Line: 384)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render() (Line: 422)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender() (Line: 201)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render() (Line: 162)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\{closure}() (Line: 564)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext() (Line: 163)
Drupal\Core\Render\MainContent\HtmlRenderer->renderResponse() (Line: 90)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\MainContentViewSubscriber->onViewRenderArray()
call_user_func() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch() (Line: 163)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle() (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle() (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle() (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle() (Line: 708)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle() (Line: 19)
```

Composer showed no errors on update and I also updated the db via drush. No errors in any logs as well.

Comment: Please add the exact command that was executed to upgrade and the output it gave.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/drupal-8-and-higher This is what I followed and afterward ran the drush update db command. Everything  performed successfully. No errors.

Comment: yes, please show the log of the whole operation, there is more info than errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what got it fixed but i restored from a backup and restarted back from 8.9.18 and cleaned up my modules folder. Some of the modules were installed via drupal UI and were just in my modules folder and not in modules/contrib so I uninstalled those modules and removed them from the modules folder and reinstalled via composer and enabled them. After that i clean up the caches and did a drush updb and continues the upgrade to 9 as i did before. And then it worked.